# pattern matching with operands

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement to validate some input from the user.

Basically the input can be of this pattern,

1. <> STRING (e.g. <> S Series )
2. = STRING  (e.g. =  Y Series )
3. < NUMBER  (e.g. <  150      )
4. >= NUMBER AND < NUMBER  (e.g. >= 150 AND < 180 )

Please share your thoughts for a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/vqCzj/1/

```
$("#check").click( function() {
    var inVal = $("#inputTxt").val();
    if(inVal.match(/^<> [a-z A-Z]+$|^= [a-z A-Z]+$|^< \d+$|^>= \d+ AND < \d+$/)) {
       $("#result").text("pass");
    } else {
        $("#result").text("fail");
    }
});
```

Comment: yes that answered my problem. thank you.